# Why does VSCode underline my pygame and how can I fix it?

Tags: python, pygame

I have the following code:

```
import pygame

win = pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))

running = True
while running:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
```

VS Code underlines pygame.QUIT and says:
Module 'pygame' has no 'QUIT' memberpylint(no-member)
The code still works so there is a quit...
Any Ideas how to fix ?

Comment: I saw that link too but I didnt quite undestand what to do

Comment: Try updating the settings.json file as mentioned in the link

Answer (score 0):

The init() function is missing

```py
pygame.init()
```

Here's the full code :

```py
import pygame
import sys

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

[Here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/pygame.html#pygame.init) is a more detailed explanation of what init does.
Do let me know through a comment if this doesn't works for you.